# Update with an incremental value based on existing value within the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

For my table below, whenever new records are added to the table, I wish to run an update statement that will populate "order_id" for relevant* records with the next incremental value available that has not been used before in the "order_id" in the same table. For example if the max(order_id) is 25, then when running the update it updates the relevant* new record with 26 (i.e. 25 +1 = 26), and then the next relevant record with 27, etc

Relevant records are new records that are added to the table which have "at_home = Y".

In the construct below, I declare `@Last_order_id` as the starting value (which would be 26 (=25+1)) to use for updates by:

```sql
DECLARE @LAST_order_id INT = ( SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM growing_list ) + 1  -- this gives 26
```

Then in my mind the update would update the first relevant record with 26, however instead it skips one and puts 27.
If I remove the "+ 1" in the declare statement then it works as I want it to but it doesnt make sense given the @last_order_id = 25, and if `SET order_id = @LAST_order_id` I would expect it to put 25!

```
drop table growing_list
create table growing_list (order_id int, info varchar(30), at_home varchar(10))

insert into growing_list (order_id , info , at_home )
    select '3' as order_id, 'Peter' as info, 'Y' as at_home union
    select null as order_id, 'Missing_Bob' as info, 'Y' as at_home union
    select '25' as order_id, 'Tall' as info, 'Y' as at_home union
    select '10' as order_id, 'dark' as info, 'Y' as at_home union
    select null as order_id, 'Missing_Jo' as info, 'N' as at_home union
    select null as order_id, 'Missing_Gar' as info, 'Y' as at_home union
    select null as order_id, 'Missing_Gar' as info, 'N' as at_home 

select * from growing_list

SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM growing_list -- 25

--DECLARE @LAST_order_id INT = ( SELECT MAX(order_id) + 1 FROM growing_list )  -- first update should be 26 (25 +1) but gives 27
--DECLARE @LAST_order_id INT = ( SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM growing_list ) + 1 -- first update should be 26 (25 +1) but gives 27
DECLARE @LAST_order_id INT = ( SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM growing_list )  -- first update should be 26 (25 +1) this gives 26 as desired
    
    UPDATE [dbo].[growing_list]
    SET order_id = @LAST_order_id, @LAST_order_id = @LAST_order_id + 1
    WHERE order_id is null
    and at_home = 'Y'

select * from growing_list
```

Comment: You created a race condition which is going cause issues at some point. Using an identity or a sequence would be a much better approach for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Make order_id int identity and do not include it in insert statement. It would be created in auto incrementing manner. ie:

```
drop table growing_list;
create table growing_list (order_id int identity not null primary key, 
    info varchar(30), at_home varchar(10));
insert into growing_list (info , at_home )
    values
    ('Peter','Y'),
    ('Missing_Bob', 'Y'),
    ('Tall', 'Y'),
    ('dark', 'Y'),
    ('Missing_Gar', 'Y');

select * from growing_list;
```

If you can explain why you want to insert nulls for 'N' then I will suggest another way like making it a normal int field and first adding 'Y' to a temp table with identity starting at max+1.

Comment: hi, thanks for this, I can see this will always give an order_id. However, the growing_list table is to capture all records (lets say good when at_home=Y and bad records when at_home=N), and only a subset of those, lets say good records, will make it to a "master" list/view'. So, the order_id should only populate for these "master" records

Comment: @madman, sorry I don't understand. order_id is for the purposes of a primary key,no?

Comment: I need order_id on just records that at_home = Y. The issue is that some of the records are from another database so the order_id they  have needs to remain static. So its only when I add new records that have at_home = Y, that new order_id should be populated.   I am trying to keep all records whether at_home = Y or N in the one table.

Comment: @madman, OK I don't understan, maybe adding a sample expected output to your question would be better.